# How do I delete all of the pages stacked through push in bottom navigation?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, navigator

I use the bottom navigation bar. Various pages remain stacks through push on A_Page, one of the bottom navigation items.

If you press the button on the top page, I want to clear all stacked pages, leaving only A_Page, the first page of the bottom navigation item. I think using Navigator.pop several times is a bad code.

How do I clear a pushed page except the first bottom navigation item page?

Comment: read all `Navigator.pop*` methods documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use named routes

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
   '/first_screen',
   (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```